# Replace formulas with static values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script copies all cells in column V and pastes them one column to the right. 
When this is done it should replace the cells with a formula in Column V with static values.

```
function newsprint() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 22, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 23));
}
```

Comment: Okay so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
function newsprint() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 22, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 23), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options) in the Google Apps Script Documentation. You need to use the `copyTo(destination, options)` method to use the `contentsOnly` parameter rather than 
`copyTo(destination)`.